# Is there an efficient way of getting a List of Strings from a List of Object?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

Is there an efficient way of of getting a list of String from a List that contains a string field.

i.e.
I have Customer Object and an Appointments Object

```
public Customer {
    String customerId;
    String name;
    List<Appointment> appointments;

    public String getCustomerId() {return customerId;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public List<Appointment> getAppointments() {return appointments;}
}

public Appointments {
    String appointmentId;
    String employee;
}
```

Now as a customer I can have several different appointment. What if I just want to get a list of all of the appointment Id's associated with the customer?

something like -> customer.getAppointments().getId;?

Comment: should be close to `customer.getAppointments().stream().map(a -> a.appointmentId).collect(toList())`

Comment: Do you mean efficient as in performance or based on readability? Streams are the most readable option in my opinion (once you get used to the notation). The notation `map(a -> a.appointmentId)` can even be replaced with `map(a::appointmentId)`. Same result, different notation.

Answer (score 5):

By using stream api:

```
List<String> idList = someCustomer.getAppointments()
    .stream()
    .map(Appointment::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: he doesn't look very familiar with stream, maybe could help him if you add the static import of toList, or just use `Collectors.`...

Comment: Stream API is far slower than traditional `for-loops`. They should only be used for handling a large amount of data that might cause memory issue, for ex: scanning a folder that contains millions of files etc

please read here( https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/)

Comment: Starting with JDK 16, you should just call `toList()` on the stream instead of `collect(Collectors.toList())`.